# Add multiple table with PHP COM("word.application")

Tags: php, ms-word, com

I wrote the following code to create multiple tables in Word using `COM("word.application")` library in PHP:

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $word->Selection->TypeText("$row[materia]\n");

            $WTable = $WrdDoc->Tables->Add($word->Selection->Range, 2, 2); // Colums, Rows
            $WrdDoc->Tables[1]->Borders->InsideLineStyle=1; 
            $WrdDoc->Tables[1]->Borders->OutsideLineStyle = 1;

            $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Width = "3"; 
            $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Width = "12";   
            $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Font->Name = "Times New Roman";
            $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Shading->BackgroundPatternColor = hexdec ( "00ff00" );
            $WTable->Cell(1,1)->Range->Text = "Strumenti compensativi";
            $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Font->Size = 18;
            $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Bold = True;
            $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Font->Italic = False;
            $WTable->Cell(1,2)->Range->Text = "$row[strumenti_compensativi]"; 

            $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Width = "3"; 
            $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Width = "12";   
            $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Range->Font->Name = "Times New Roman";
            $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Range->Shading->BackgroundPatternColor = hexdec ( "00ff00" );
            $WTable->Cell(2,1)->Range->Text = "Misure dispensative";
            $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Font->Size = 14;
            $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Bold = False;
            $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Font->Italic = False;
            $WTable->Cell(2,2)->Range->Text = "$row[misure_dispensative]";              
        }
```

The second table is written into the first one. It doesn't go on.
Maybe the problem is to collapse the range, but I have no idea how can I do it.
Please! Help me!